# Re-Quantize Already Quantized Models

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Is it possible to re-quantize already quantized models?

I have some models that I have trained with Quantization Aware Training (QAT) with **Full Integer Quantization**. However, I am failing to do GPU Delegation with those models. Is there a way to make the models I already have with **Float16** Quantization in order to be able to run them with ***GPU Delegate***.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for some ways to convert integer quantized model fo float16 quantized model?

Which version of TFLite are you using? TFLite 2.3 supports running quantized models with GPU delegate. However, as GPU only supports float operations, so it internally dequantize integer weights into float weights.
Please see the doc for how to enable (experimental) quantized model support. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu_advanced#running_quantized_models_experimental

Comment: This probably should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).